# How to setup an MQTT broker on Tiny Core 6.x ARM 7

Tags: linux, mqtt, raspberry-pi2, mosquitto, paho

I am looking for an MQTT broker extension for [tiny core](http://www.tinycorelinux.net) 6.x Armv7 (since I use tiny core on Raspberry PI 2 - http://www.tinycorelinux.net/6.x/armv7/), preferably Mosquitto (if not then Paho would do as well).

Being new to tiny core & MQTT, I may be missing something. I would really appreciate if someone could guide me on this.

Comment: that's a question for the system admin stack exchange

Comment: http://superuser.com/

Comment: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com . Good luck.

Comment: This question is related to MQTT framework, and running one of its tools - mosquito / paho on a certain version of linux. I do not see it being solely related to pi2. Also, I cannot find tags like "mqtt" or "mosquito" on stack exchange. @shelter correct me and I would happily move it.